# Why doesn't my website load some images?

Tags: jquery, image, html, portfolio

This is my website tryout upload:

[My portfolio](http://grozav.t15.org/Portfolio.html)

it seems that some images are not loaded, and the divs which have `display:none` also load themselves even if not triggered. It works perfectly when it's not uploaded.
Please view my jquery or whatever code and tell me what I did wrong.
How can I fix this please? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regarding the images - your server is case sensitive, so your HTML is trying to load the file:
http://grozav.t15.org/thumb/RealEstate.jpg

when the actual filename is:
http://grozav.t15.org/thumb/realestate.jpg

Update your HTML with the correct filenames.